# ORA-40478 when returning large json into clob in Oracle 19c

Tags: json, oracle, clob

In Oracle 19c I created the table:

```
create table SAMPLE_TABLE (
id NUMBER not null,
display_name  NVARCHAR2(4000), )
```

When I run the script:

```
declare    
   i integer;   
   p_tmp_clob clob;
 begin   
   select JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(t.* )) into p_tmp_clob from SAMPLE_TABLE t;
end;
```

I am getting the following ORA-40478 exception.
ORA-40478: output value too large (maximum: 4000)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to tell the function to [return a CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370), not a varchar:

It might be necessary for JSON_ARRAYAGG as well (or maybe only there - I can't test it right now)

```
declare    
   i integer;   
   p_tmp_clob clob;
 begin   
   select JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(t.* RETURNING CLOB) RETURNING CLOB) 
     into p_tmp_clob 
   from SAMPLE_TABLE t;
end;
```

Comment: Yes this is correct-- confirming it worked for me. Additionally, no you don't need `returning clob` on the inner `json_object` unless you do :) (if you go over default `varchar2(4000)`), but I also wonder what happens if you try to cast a clob to a clob?

Note: you'll possibly want to `COALESCE(<all that>, TO_CLOB('[]'])` if you, like me, want an empty array in the event of no results from that inner select query.

Comment: One more gem for you: append `format json` to every _value_ you don't want to be turned into a string. Oh dang - I got limited by Comment. Lemme add another answer to exemplify my point..

Answer (score 2):

To supplement my suggestions in a comment response to @a_horse_with_no_name's correct answer above:

In the end, in all, you need

- a combo of `COALESCE`
- with a clob-compatible fallback of json array
- and `RETURNING CLOB` in each `json_agg*` function (to be safe: it's only *needed* on the one wrapping content larger than `varchar2(4000)` and any `json_agg*` function wrapping it (ie: both inner object and outer array)
- on each thing that could return an empty resultset

Example:

```
SELECT
  coalesce(
    json_arrayagg(
      json_object(
        'something' value 'Something',
        'staticEmptyArrayString' value to_clob('[]'),
        'staticEmptyArrayReally' value to_clob('[]') format json,
        'reallyEmptyArrayNull' value (SELECT to_clob('') FROM dual),
        'reallyEmptyArray' value COALESCE((SELECT to_clob('') FROM dual), to_clob('[]')) format json,
        'reallyEmptyArrayToo' value COALESCE((SELECT to_clob('') FROM dual), to_clob('[]')) format json,
        'reallyEmptyArrayAlso' value COALESCE((SELECT to_clob('') FROM dual), to_clob('[]'))
        format json
        returning clob
      )
      returning clob
    ),
    to_clob('[]')
  ) AS json_out
  FROM dual;
```

begets:

```
[
  {
    "something": "Something",
    "staticEmptyArrayString": "[]",
    "staticEmptyArrayReally": [],
    "reallyEmptyArrayNull": null,
    "reallyEmptyArray": [],
    "reallyEmptyArrayToo": [],
    "reallyEmptyArrayAlso": []
  }
]
```

Comment: I could not figure out how to slide in something that is actually a nested array of values in my static, dual-using examples:

`'realArray' value json_arrayagg((SELECT 'abc' FROM dual UNION SELECT '123' FROM dual)) format json,` didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

> The character string returned by this function is of data type
>   VARCHAR2. This clause allows you to specify the size of the VARCHAR2
>   data type. Use BYTE to specify the size as a number of bytes or CHAR
>   to specify the size as a number of characters. The default is BYTE. If
>   you omit this clause, or if you specify this clause but omit the size
>   value, **then JSON_OBJECT returns a character string of type
>   VARCHAR2(4000)**.